# Capitalizar primera letra una palabra

Tags: java, string

Quiero capitalizar la primera letra de todas las palabras de una frase 
 EJ:

> hola mundo

Y la respuesta esperada es:

> Hola Mundo

Estoy usando java y no he logrado generar un método que pueda hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static String convierte(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(string," ");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        String ne = (String)st.nextElement();
        if (ne.length()>0) {
            builder.append(ne.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
            builder.append(ne.substring(1).toLowerCase()); //agregado
            builder.append(' ');
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```